# Perspective correct texture mapping in Pixi.js

Tags: 3d, texture-mapping, perspective, pixi.js

My purpose is making a simple 3d engine with 2D sprite (I choose Pixi.js this time as I can control the vertices of sprite arbitrarily), but I cannot understand how to map the texture to a perspective projected quad correctly.

texture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rshDq.jpg

I am using the PIXI.mesh.Plane for the quad, if the subdivision is low

```
var verticesX = 2, verticesY = 2;
this.field = new PIXI.mesh.Plane(resources['palette'].texture, verticesX , verticesY );
```

This will give out the result of screenshot01: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AUd4.jpg

You can see the texture mapping is incorrect.

Goes on I increase the division to 4 after the projection to screen vertices, and calculate the division point linearly.

```
this.field = new PIXI.mesh.Plane(resources['palette'].texture, 5, 5);
var lt = [this.field.model.screenVertices[0], this.field.model.screenVertices[1]];
var rt = [this.field.model.screenVertices[2], this.field.model.screenVertices[3]];
var rb = [this.field.model.screenVertices[4], this.field.model.screenVertices[5]];
var lb = [this.field.model.screenVertices[6], this.field.model.screenVertices[7]];
var segX = this.field.verticesX - 1;
var segY = this.field.verticesY - 1;
var vertices = [];
for (var i = 0; i < (segY + 1); i++) {
  var l = (lb[0] - lt[0]) / segY * i + lt[0];
  var r = (rb[0] - rt[0]) / segY * i + rt[0];
  for (var j = 0; j < (segX + 1); j++) {
    var t = (rt[1] - lt[1]) / segX * j + lt[1];
    var b = (rb[1] - lb[1]) / segX * j + lb[1];
    vertices[(i * (segY + 1) + j) * 2] = (r - l) / segX * j + l;
    vertices[(i * (segY + 1) + j) * 2 + 1] = (b - t) / segY * i + t;
  }
}
this.field.vertices.set(vertices);
```

that is 4x4 division as 5 points for each edges, the result is shown as screenshot02: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qi22.jpg, but the height of each division is the same, the illusion of perspective is broken


How can I achieve the result as the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7EZk.jpg

The height of division proportion to the depth respectively

Or am I heading to a wrong direction to solve the problem, please suggest me some advise, thanks.

PS. The debug message in the screen is describing the vertices coordinate of the field lay on ground in clipping space, not the screen space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply perspective and calculate your (x2, y2) coordinates from a (x3, y3, z3) 3D space point.

The simplest perspective transform equations are:

x2 = x3 / z3

y2 = y3 / z3

being (x3, y3, z3) space defined as (0, 0, 0) is the camera position, z is the viewing direction, x3 is the horizontal perpencitular axis and y3 is the vertical perpendicular axis. And for the 2D (x2, y2) the (0, 0) should be the center of the screen.

You can read more in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Perspective_projection and in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Weak_perspective_projection

To get something rendered, a visible quad, you can try these 3D points should work:
(100, -100, 3), (100, -100, 5), (-100, -100, 5), (-100, -100, 3)

Now, subdivide in 3D coordinates, not in 2D coordinates and calculate for each 3D vertex the 2D projected position.

You probably will need to apply 3D transforms to move and rotate camera and objects, check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Examples_in_3D_computer_graphics

However you will still have problems with texture perspective correction if you use an image. The more subdivisions, the less problems.

I think it will be better to use three.js or other webgl library.